# Trying to set up windows in Selenium and instead i am getting them tabbed into 1 browser window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webautomation

I am currently working on a project and cant seem to find what is going wrong with my python code,
I wish to create 3 different windows but they keep merging into 1?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
site_url='https://www.google.com'
driver.get(site_url)
driver.set_window_size(1280, 1000)
driver.set_window_position(0,0)
x=640
for i in range (2): 
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i+1])
    driver.set_window_size(1280, 1000)
    driver.set_window_position(x,0)
    driver.get(site_url)
    x+=640
```

my monitor is 1920 by 1080 and I intend for them to be overlapping but start perfectly every third of the screen

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.common.exceptions
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver import EventFiringWebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.events import AbstractEventListener


from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
site_url = 'https://www.google.com'
driver.get(site_url)
driver.set_window_size(1280, 1000)
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
x = 640
for i in range(2):
    driver.execute_script(
        'window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank","1");')
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i+1])
    driver.set_window_size(1280, 1000)
    driver.set_window_position(x, 0)
    driver.get(site_url)
    x += 640
```

just give window name and some junk window feature value as shown:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open